# Read_gservices permission not found in android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to integrate Google maps in my android project. I have installed latest Google play services in my emulator and given all the necessary permissions in the manifest file. It still shows that G_services not found.

Comment: Did you add this library in your project?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.google.android.gms.common.app.GmsApplication: java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission: Neither user 10069 nor current process has com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.

Comment: Yes, I have already added google play services library in my project.

Comment: <permission
        android:name="com.indoor.positioning.system.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" >
    </permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.indoor.positioning.system.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: have you added   <meta-data 
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> inside application tag?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 7327000 but found 7571000.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: Yes, you're doing mistake. Your meta tag is not. inside the application tag. For more I'm giving you an answer, if it works tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Your metadata tag is inside the  tag. Remove and place it right after the application tag:

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/logo"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyBOhdOOMI_ZMYlvSyi7DVeRe_bo9ckxehM" />
<meta-data
    android:name="android.app.searchable"
    android:resource="@layout/searchable" />
</application>
```